# How to use Set-ACL to give Read Permissions / Replicate an icacls command?

Tags: powershell

Upfront, I am not very familiar with powershell, so apologies in advance. So, I am trying to set several hundred folders worth of permissions (generating the commands via a programming loop).

I am struggling to understand the format of the Set-ACL command, so I was hoping someone could assist me by spelling out the command I would need to replicate the following icacls. As I will be generating hundreds of these via a scripting loop, I would much prefer if it was all self-contained on a single line, even if things have to be spelled out, rather than using helper variables.

The commands would be for Read Access, and "full access"

`icacls "\\Path\to\share\folder" /grant DOMAIN\USER:R`

and

`icacls "\\Path\to\share\folder" /grant DOMAIN\USER:(OI)(CI)M /T`

Comment: Note that, given that `icacls.exe` is an external executable, you can just call it directly from PowerShell, so there is no strict need to translate to [`Set-Acl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-acl) - or is there a performance concern?